# How do I create a new SQL table with a percentage column which is conditional on whether information shows up in two other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables, the table called agg((date,sname,open,high,low,close,volume)) contains daily information for every stock for x number of past years. Another table, split(date,sname,post,pre), has info for every time any stock split. Another table, div(date,sname,dividend), has info for every time a stock had a dividend. I want to create a new table, with a column that gives the percent change from closing of the previous day, to the day after, for every stock and every day listed in agg.
Here is the line I have for just the daily change, not including div and split:

```
create table daily 
as    
with prevclose as (   
  select date,sname,close,    
         lag(close) over (partition by symbol order by date) pclose   
  from agg   
)  
select a.*, 
       100.0*(close - pclose)/(case when pclose=0 then null else pclose end) as prcnt  
from prevclose a  
where pclose != 0;
```

I want to change this code to incorporate the change in split and dividends which is not incorporated in the agg table. I don't even need the full calculation for this, but I need help figuring out how to incorporate the condition into the new table. I only need to add in split and div info if there is split and div info for that particular date and time. I think if I could just see the query for a similar problem it would help.

Comment: Why would a left join not work against those tables?

Comment: @RossBush I'm pretty new to sql, I think you're right that it could work. Does left join allow me to specify that only 2 certain columns need to match? Or does the entire row have to match?

Comment: Yes, you would need to LEFT JOIN both tables on the conditions you require. Null values from the joined tables on key fields would mean no div or split was found for the give day for that particular ticker symbol.

Comment: @RossBush Okay that makes sense, thank you so much